# Pass a string with double and single quotes from asp to javascript function

Tags: javascript, string, asp-classic, escaping, quotes

I have the following code:

```
PropertyID = 101
PropertyName = "My'complex" property name"" //This is passed from sql query
Response.Write "<a href=""javascript:RenameFunc("& PropertyID & ", '" & PropertyName  & "' )"" onclick=""""></a>"
```

The problem is that If I have single or double quotes in my variables, the javascript function brakes (which is normal).

I tried escaping them like this:

```
 Response.Write "<a href=""javascript:RenameFunc("& PropertyID & ", '" & Replace(Replace(PropertyName,"'",""),"""","")  & "' )"" onclick=""""> </a>"
```

This doesn't break the function, but it removes the quotes from my string and I need them.

I also tried with `String.row` like this:

```
Response.Write "<a href=""javascript:RenameFunc("& PropertyID & ", String.raw`"& PropertyName &"` )"" onclick=""""> </a>"
```

Still no success, but maybe I use it the wrong way.

Is there any other way to pass the string and keep it as it is, without breaking the javascript function?

Comment: Have you tried with `Server.HTMLEncode()`?

Comment: Just now I tried and it works! :) Thanks. Write it as an answer if you want and I will accept it. I knew it will be something simple....

Comment: Some bed time reading... http://stackoverflow.com/a/143410/692942

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Server.HTMLEncode()` helper:

```
Response.Write "<a href=""javascript:RenameFunc("& PropertyID & ", '" & Server.HtmlEncode(Replace(PropertyName,"'","\'")) & "')"" onclick=""""> </a>"
```

See [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: So it turned out that I still have problems with the single quotes, but i fixed it using   `'" & Server.HtmlEncode(Replace(PropertyName,"'","\'")) & "'` Now it works great.